# Flash CS5 and the App Store TOS

Tags: iphone, flash, app-store, appstore-approval

Has Apple been known to recently reject apps that were created in Flash CS5?

Also, If I submit an app that violates the TOS, am I risking my Paid Developer status, or just having my app rejected?

Comment: What is a Flash App for iPhone?

Comment: @Ghommey - As opposed to before when they did?

Comment: I have been wondering this too. I mean yes, the license says no they wont accept it, but I am curious to see if they are actively enforcing this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [the app store approval process is off topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Adobe® Flash® Professional CS5 software ships with Adobe AIR® Packager for iPhone and offers the technical capability to have ActionScript 3 projects run as native applications for the iPhone 3.0 OS. As a result of Apple’s updated legal terms (section 3.3.1 of the Apple iPhone SDK License Agreement), Apple is no longer permitting these applications to be delivered to iPhone, iPad and iPod touch users through the Apple App Store. This a legal restriction imposed by Apple and is not a technical limitation of Adobe AIR or Adobe Flash Professional CS5.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/

That means although you are able to install it on your iPhone with OS3 by using a cable they will reject any app beeing sent to the appstore.

Comment: Well, does submission of such an app invalidate my developer license?

Comment: I guess so but I cant tell for sure. As soon as you send a new version Apple tests it against the rules and might see that your current app also violates their terms

Comment: Moshe: as far as I know you don't risk anything except having the app rejected - that is, having it rejected because it uses Flash is no different from having it rejected because it uses the wrong kind of icons, or shows bikinis, or whatever. When last I actually heard though, Flash apps were not being rejected, they were just sitting in limbo. I don't know if that has changed now that iOS4 is released.